# android: a text editor and NOTHING ELSE

Tags: android, text-editor

1. I don't need support for dropbox.
2. I don't need support for "sharing". The text editor is allowed No Internet Access Whatsoever.
3. I already have a file browser. I don't need another one.
4. I don't want or need text formatting, i.e. bold, italic, font family and size changes. Syntax highlighting, I could deal with.

It absolutely baffles me that such a text editor should be so hard to find, but for the life of me, I can not find one with this feature set. All I want is to open, edit, and create new text files from my file browser. (My file browser does not come with an integrated text editor for exactly the same reasons I don't want a text editor with an integrated file browser. I will not migrate from my file browser. It's the default file browser in LineageOS in case you're wondering.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Editor**](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.billthefarmer.editor/) is 88KB! Available on F-Droid.

> This is a very simple generic text editor which may be used standalone
> or to show or edit any sort of text file from another app. If you
> select a text file in a file manager or similar app you will be
> offered the option of using this editor along with whatever other apps
> you have installed that can show or edit a text file.

[**Text Edit**](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.paulmach.textedit/) is 128KB - Available on F-Droid.

> Text Edit is a simple notepad application. It opens, edits and saves text files on the SD card.
>
> Unfortunately, this app is not recommended for large files. The author has decided to stop working on the app so any future updates
> are unlikely.

Comment: Editor is highly serviceable! FDroid is weird. No ratings, no searches sorted by popularity, # downloads, or anything, but Editor is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Not that hard to find if you know [where to look](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/search)¹ and can live with the share functionality by simply not using it. Found you a few candidates which all come without INTERNET permission, and are leightweight:

**[Jota Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota)** weights less than 800kB. It supports quite long text files (up to 1MB), multiple encodings – but no frills: no Internet, Dropbox, no formatting. Can be used on Android 1.6 to 8.0.

An alternative candidat: **[NTW Text Editor Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=robbin.android.NeedToWrite_Trial)** is even smaller (less than 600kB). It also supports multiple encodings, lets you change the font *size* (you certainly won't complain about that), and sets no limit on the size of the text file you're editing. Undo/redo, text search with wildcard support, and auto-save are features you certainly won't complain about.

**[Material Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bijoysingh.quicknote)** is also [available on F-Droid](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.bijoysingh.quicknote) (via my repository), if you like a more up-to-date design. It's a bit bigger, though, and supports "rich text" (ie. formatting), so it might not be your first choice. Though you simply could ignore that feature, as the GUI is kept simple enough.

I certainly could continue with some more candidates – but so can you, using either the initial link to search apps by category and permissions, or go to the respective categories directly and watch out for those candidates having a low number of permissions without a "red border". Enjoy!

---

¹ <sub>Disclosure: Link goes to my Android website</sub>

Comment: Interesting. Can Material Notes save to text files? If so, how is the formatting saved? Markdown?

Comment: I have not tried it, so I can't tell, sorry.

Comment: the search engine is pretty impressive btw.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's limited to the ~14k apps in my lists … If you want to search the entire Playstore, you could take a look at the StripSearch app – see my article [StripSearch helps you find apps by permission](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/stripsearch-finds-apps-by-permissions).